# I need to make the sum of an column in javascript

Tags: javascript

This is html code that i can't edit :

```
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">Expense name</th>
          <th scope="col">Value per unity (lei)</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>Water</td>
          <td class="expense">62</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>Netflix subscription</td>
          <td class="expense">49.50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">3</th>
          <td>Juice</td>
          <td class="expense">16.40</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">4</th>
          <td>New phone</td>
          <td class="expense">2599</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <h2>
        Total expenses this month (lei):
        <div id="total-expenses"></div>
    </h2>
```

My question is :
How do i do that in code(javascript)?
I have something in my head but i don t know how to write that. What i have in head is: i declare variable for  expenses,or using this queryselector(but i don t know how to point at specific td, because i have 2 td's in 1 tr) and after i can make a function with sum of that column, but i don't know how to write that in code. Can someone help me

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to select all nodes that have `.expense`. Then you should iterate and calculate the `total`. After that write the total into `#total-expenses`.

```js
// select nodes for expense
const expenceNodes = document.querySelectorAll('.expense');

let total = 0.0;

// calculating total
expenceNodes.forEach(node => {
  total += parseFloat(node.innerText);
})

// write total
document.getElementById('total-expenses').innerText = total.toFixed(2);
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">Expense name</th>
          <th scope="col">Value per unity (lei)</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>Water</td>
          <td class="expense">62</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>Netflix subscription</td>
          <td class="expense">49.50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">3</th>
          <td>Juice</td>
          <td class="expense">16.40</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">4</th>
          <td>New phone</td>
          <td class="expense">2599</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <h2>
        Total expenses this month (lei):
        <div id="total-expenses"></div>
    </h2>
```

Comment: thank you a lot!